# calling function, echoing results

Tags: php, function

I'm trying to get this function to work where it returns the file location on the server. at the bottom of the coding I show how i'm trying to display the coding in my other pages. Am i right when echo'ing the last line of coding to get it to display when calling the function?

```
function record_loc($id,$type) 
{
  $recdir = mysql_result(mysql_query(
      "SELECT rec_loc FROM names WHERE com_id = '".$id."'"), 0 , "rec_loc");

  $ver = ($type == 'n' ? '-n.wav' : '-s.wav');
  // echo '/doc_rec/' . $recdir . '/' . $id . $ver;
return '/doc_rec/' . $recdir . '/' . $id . $ver;
} 

// echo record_loc(120,n); or <?= record_loc(120,n) 
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example would, in fact, output the data (just due to simplicity of the statement), however what's really happening it the function is echoing first, then the echo [commented in this case] is performed.  e.g.

```
function return_some_value(){
  return 'abc';
}
function echo_some_value(){
  echo 'def';
}

echo return_some_value() . echo_some_value();
```

output would result in echo_some_value displaying out first (and returning null) which is then passed to echo for further execution. e.g.

```
defabc
```

(though you'd expect `abcdef`)

**EDIT** per request in comment to this Answer **EDIT**

```
function record_loc($id,$type) 
{
  if (($query = mysql_query("SELECT rec_loc FROM names WHERE com_id = '".(int)$id."'")) !== false)
  {
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
      return '/doc_rec/'.mysql_result($query,0,'rec_loc').'/'.$id.'-'.($type=='n'?'n':'s').'.wav';
  }
  return 'Error Not Found';
}
```

*Please note you should be checking your connection, checking for sql errors and validating input. I have not exhausted all the checks, just making your code do what what you requested.*

Comment: i made the change and removed echo and added return... does that look right? i'll then use <?= record_loc(120,n)?> to display the coding on my other pages.

Comment: Yes, your new version looks accurate. You can also shorten the return with `return '/doc_rec/' . $recdir . '/' . $id . '-' ($type=='n'?'n':'s').'.wav';` if you'd like. (Also, if $type is expected to be a string, call the function using `record_loc(120,'n');`)

Comment: is there a way to make it return an error string like "Error Not Found" when a sql entry is not there?

Comment: Please see my updated post. This should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

There is a functional difference between using `return` and an output operator like `echo, print, print_r, sprint` etc.

See here for [return](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) and here for [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

Namely:

> 'return' *returns* its argument as the
>   value of the function call
>
> 'echo' *outputs* one or more strings

So, return in your function passes the result as a value you can give to a variable, i.e. `$myvar=myfunction();`, you would then need to echo `$myvar` (or do echo myfunction();), whereas with echo in your function, simply having `myfunction();` would accomplish the same. Use return when you want to pass the result of a function through other operations.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understand the question. But you can't echo a function if it doesn't return anything.

Here is a simple function that returns a value:

```
<?php
function do_stuff() {
    return rand(1, 10);
}

echo do_stuff();
?>

<?= do_stuff() ?>
```

Comment: when echo inside of the function do i have to put the variables too... echo record_loc(120,n); inside the function then <?= record_loc(120,n) ?> in my other pages

Comment: `<?= do_stuff() ?>` is short for `<?php echo do_stuff(); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Or you return the path and use `echo record_loc(120,n);`

Or you echo the path in the return (like the sample) and use `<?php record_loc(120,n) ?>`